# How to #include <x11/xlib.h> in oepncv?

Tags: opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.4.6 with VS2010 in Windows 7. I could not include x11/xlib.h header file in a program. Can anyone help me that how can i include it with a program?

## include "x11/xlib.h"// Could not include.

Answer (score 0):

x11 only exists on linux / mac.

where did you find that include line ?

if it was in some demo code, you can't use it on win

Comment: I am using the source code below from github. How can i use this source code in VS2010 with Windows 7? https://github.com/jujojujo2003/OpenCVHandGuesture/blob/master/main.cpp

Comment: i'm sure, you can replace all windowing functionality with code from opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp